# Java application authentication using Active Directory

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, ldap, cas

I am working on a third party Java application for which I need to authenticate its users using Active Directory.

This application is hosted on RHEL 6.5, and uses LDAP to authenticate with Windows Active Directory. The AD server has been set up, and is working fine with an earlier version of the application (which was configured to enable the integration).

For the newer version, the vendor has laid out some steps to modify/configure the application files to connect with the AD server, and which are expected to help us authenticate. After making required changes, we are only able to open the UI page, which does not accept the (correct) credentials, the page that helps us with application configuration is not accessible at all.

I am a newbie to this area, and as far as my understanding goes, I would just need to make the suggested changes, and not follow the steps presented in [this document](http://people.redhat.com/mskinner/rhug/q3.2013/ready_rhel_ad/refarch_rhel6_to_ad.pdf), as those are for authenticating the Linux users, and NOT the application's users. Could someone also please confirm the same.

Any help/guidance in this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much!

Edit:
I am unable to provide details of the files as it is confidential property, but the changes have to be made in the server property files.
Kindly request more details if necessary, I will try my best to provide them as I can't disclose everything, citing confidentiality reasons.

Thank you very much.

Edit 2:
Have added more details with this edit, which are given below:
The application has one of its component as CAS, which is currently configured to use database as its authentication handler. When we enter the credentials - username: abcd, password: samplepswd, we are able to login successfully.

As the business requirement is that of authentication with Active Directory using LDAP, we have to modify the CAS properties file. As per instructions from the product vendor, we have changed the following properties to use ldap -

```
authenticationHandler.type=ldap
ldapSSLConfig.enabled=false
ldapContextSource.url=ldap://sample.ADserver.example.net:389
ldapContextSource.userDn=abcd
ldapContextSource.password=samplepswd
ldapAuthenticationHandler.filter=uid=%u
ldapAuthenticationHandler.searchBase=OU=DEF,OU=PQR,OU=XYZ,DC=ADserver,DC=example,DC=net
```

We also need to make changes in the casAuthConfig xml file for the following properties (as anonymous search is not supported):
1. anonymousReadOnly, value is set to false
2. java.naming.security.authentication, value is set to simple

There is provision to use ldap over SSL as well, but currently we are not using that.
However, if we do use SSL, additional changes have to be made to the following properties:

```
ldapSSLConfig.enabled=true
ldapSSLConfig.trustStorePath=/home/dir1/subdir1/subdir2/keystorename.keystore
ldapSSLConfig.trustStoreType=jceks
```

These are the only configuration changes done on our (client) side; and in fact the only changes done. Nothing has been added/modified on the server (AD server), except another user, but that has no impact on the existing setup.

After restarting cas to reflect the changes, we encounter the error of bad credentials, although the values entered are correct:
2015-09-16 12:12:30,558 INFO [com.emeter.cas.authentication.support.DelegatingAuthenticationHandler] - Authenticating credential using handler

```
com.emeter.cas.adaptors.ldappwd.BindLdapAuthenticationHandler 
2015-09-16 12:12:30,558 DEBUG [com.emeter.cas.authentication.support.DelegatingAuthenticationHandler] - credentials.getUsername() = abcd
2015-09-16 12:12:30,672 INFO [com.emeter.cas.adaptors.ldappwd.BindLdapAuthenticationHandler] - Search for cn=abcd returned 0 results. 
2015-09-16 12:12:30,672 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - AuthenticationHandler: 

com.emeter.cas.authentication.support.DelegatingAuthenticationHandler failed to authenticate the user which provided the following credentials: 

[username: abcd] 
2015-09-16 12:12:30,676 ERROR [org.jasig.cas.integration.restlet.TicketResource] - error.authentication.credentials.bad 
org.jasig.cas.ticket.TicketCreationException: error.authentication.credentials.bad 
at org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.createTicketGrantingTicket_aroundBody10(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:423)
```

Can anybody please help with this issue? Or possibly point in the right direction?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You want us to check the statements in a document you haven't provided?

Comment: Hello @EJP, I am unable to provide the details of the document (s), as it is confidential, and I know that's not very helpful. But I can share that the changes have been suggested in the property files of the CAS server.
For now, could you please confirm whether I need to follow the steps given in the pdf or would I only need to change the server properties?

Thanks very much.

Comment: @EJP, have updated the question with more details. Could you please take a look at it now? Thanks!